# Pip install numpy throws a TypeError Exception IronPython 2.7

Tags: numpy, pip, ironpython

I'm doing an internship in a company where I have a project about integrating Python into an existing C# project. So adding the two libs NumPy and SciPy would be really important.
There are some limitations because of the old Python version which is why I struggle a bit.

So what I do is trying to install NumPy over pip as following:

> pip install --proxy="proxy:port" numpy

What I get is an exception. I already tried to upgrade pip because I thought it might solve the problem but no success.
Does anyone have a clue what could be the cause of this problem?

```
DEPRECATION: pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\ironpython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 223, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\program files\ironpython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 180, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "c:\program files\ironpython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 320, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "c:\program files\ironpython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\legacy\resolver.py", line 180, in resolve
    discovered_reqs.extend(self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req))
  File "c:\program files\ironpython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\legacy\resolver.py", line 385, in _resolve_one
    dist = self._get_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "c:\program files\ironpython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\legacy\resolver.py", line 336, in _get_dist_for
    self._populate_link(req)
  File "c:\program files\ironpython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\legacy\resolver.py", line 302, in _populate_link
    req.link = self._find_requirement_link(req)
  File "c:\program files\ironpython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\legacy\resolver.py", line 267, in _find_requirement_link
    best_candidate = self.finder.find_requirement(req, upgrade)
  File "c:\program files\ironpython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 899, in find_requirement
    best_candidate_result = self.find_best_candidate(
  File "c:\program files\ironpython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 882, in find_best_candidate
    candidates = self.find_all_candidates(project_name)
  File "c:\program files\ironpython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 825, in find_all_candidates
    package_links = self.process_project_url(
  File "c:\program files\ironpython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 789, in process_project_url
    html_page = self._link_collector.fetch_page(project_url)
  File "c:\program files\ironpython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\collector.py", line 618, in fetch_page
    return _get_html_page(location, session=self.session)
  File "c:\program files\ironpython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\collector.py", line 430, in _get_html_page
    resp = _get_html_response(url, session=session)
  File "c:\program files\ironpython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\collector.py", line 127, in _get_html_response
    resp = session.get(
  File "c:\program files\ironpython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 555, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "c:\program files\ironpython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\session.py", line 428, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\program files\ironpython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 528, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "c:\program files\ironpython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 456, in prepare_request
    p.prepare(
  File "c:\program files\ironpython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\models.py", line 316, in prepare
    self.prepare_url(url, params)
  File "c:\program files\ironpython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\models.py", line 382, in prepare_url
    scheme, auth, host, port, path, query, fragment = parse_url(url)
  File "c:\program files\ironpython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\url.py", line 381, in parse_url
    host = _normalize_host(host, scheme)
  File "c:\program files\ironpython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\url.py", line 296, in _normalize_host
    return six.ensure_str(
  File "c:\program files\ironpython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 951, in ensure_str
    raise TypeError("not expecting type '%s'" % type(s))
TypeError: not expecting type '<type 'bytes'>'
```

Thank you in advance!

**Update October 6th:**

I changed the pip install command for installing NumPy to:

```
pip install --proxy="proxy:port" numpy==1.6.6
```

Because I know that this was the last version which has been compatible with python 2.7 but I had no success. It throws the same error but the file where the exception is thrown is different:

```
pip install --proxy="xxx:port" --user numpy==1.6.6
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
DEPRECATION: A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\FurkanK\AppData\Roaming\Python\IronPython27\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 186, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\program files\ironpython 2.7\Lib\contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "c:\program files\ironpython 2.7\Lib\contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\FurkanK\AppData\Roaming\Python\IronPython27\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_tracker.py", line 42, in update_env_context_manager
    yield
TypeError: not expecting type '<type 'bytes'>'
```

The next step I took is changing the pip version to an old one:

```
pip install pip==20.0.1
```

After that I tried to install the older NumPy version I mentioned above, but it didn't work aswell.

I don't really know what else I could do. I think the problem must be the latest 2.7.11 IronPython version because even changing the pip versions isn't really helping. Does anyone else have any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to use python libraries using C-extensions with IronPython.

You may have better luck using [Python.NET](http://pythonnet.github.io/) instead, as that integrates with CPython under the hood.